# Sharing an ESM ".js" module within Node / Electron environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, electron

In my Electron app I have a large file `constants.js` that is exported and available throughout the **Render Process** (Web, ESM Modules).  I would like to also import this file in the application's **Main Process** (Node, CJS Modules).

Even with the new experimental modules that are available in the latest versions of Electron/Node, that would require changing my file extension from `constants.js` to `constants.mjs`.  As this file is heavily references throughout the application changing the file extension is not an option.

Is it possible to share my `constants.js` file between both the Render and Main Processes?

**Project Structure:**

```
root
│
├── build (main process)
│   ├── mainElectron.js
│   └── package.json
│
├── source (render process)
│   └── js
│       └── index.js
│       └── support
│           └── constants.js
│
└── package.json
```

**constants.js**

```
export {

    Location,
    People,
};

const Location = {

    COUNTRY: "Canada",
    CITY: "Montreal"
};

const People = {

    OWNER: "Mr. Owner",
    MANAGER: "Mrs. Manager",
    DEVELOPER: "Mr. Developer",
};
```

**index.js** *(Render Process, Web ESM)*

```
import * as C from "../support/constants.js";

console.log(`${C.People.DEVELOPER} lives in ${C.Location.CITY}`);
```

**mainElectron.js** *(Main Process, Node CJS)*

```
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;

app.on("ready", () => {

    //How to access constants.js file here?
});
```

Comment: From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981122/how-to-include-javascript-for-both-main-process-and-renderer) seems that `require` allows loading js files in both main and render process

Comment: I would have to add it to my `node_modules` folder, which I don't want to do for several reasons.  Also, my Main Process has its own own separate set of `node_modules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this question in the future with the same problem, I solved it by using:

**[ESM:  Tomorrow's ECMAScript modules today!](https://github.com/standard-things/esm)**.

Further, I restructured my code so that the constants file I am sharing between the *Main Process* and the *Renderer Process* is now located within my `./build` folder with the *Main Process* files.

**Project Structure:**

```
root
│
├── build (main process)
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   ├── mainElectronESM.js
│   │   │   └── mainElectron.js
│   │   └── support
│   │       └── constants.js
│   └── package.json
│
├── source (render process)
│   └── js
│       └── index.js
│
└── package.json
```

**constants.js**

```
export {

    Location,
    People,
};

const Location = {

    COUNTRY: "Canada",
    CITY: "Montreal"
};

const People = {

    OWNER: "Mr. Owner",
    MANAGER: "Mrs. Manager",
    DEVELOPER: "Mr. Developer",
};
```

**mainElectronESM.js** *(Main Process, Node CJS)*

```
require = require("esm")(module);
module.exports = require("./mainElectron.js");
```

**mainElectron.js** *(Main Process, Node ESM)*

```
import { app } from "electron";
import * as C from "../support/constants.js";

app.on("ready", () => {

    console.log(`${C.People.DEVELOPER} lives in ${C.Location.CITY}`);
});
```

**index.js** *(Render Process, Web ESM)*

```
import * as C from "../../build/js/support/constants.js";

console.log(`${C.People.DEVELOPER} lives in ${C.Location.CITY}`);
```

Comment: Breaks top-level await which can be annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Like TheDarkin1978 I share a `constants.js` file between `main` and `renderer` processes, without needing ESM.

Just FYI, this is a react application using create-react-app.

Application layout:

```
root
 ├── src
 │    ├─ main/
 │    ├─ renderer/
 │    ├─ constants.js
 │    ├─ electron.js (electron main entry point)
 │    └─ index.tsx (webpack / renderer entry point)
 └── package.json
```

`constants.js`

```
const WindowEvent = {
  close: "app-close",
  maximise: "win-maximise",
  minimise: "win-minimise"
}

const WindowQuery = {
  isMaximised: "is-maximised"
}

module.exports = { WindowEvent, WindowQuery }
```

`main/index.js`

```
const { WindowEvent } = require("../constants")
```

`renderer/ipc/window.js`

```
const { WindowQuery } = require("../../constants")
```