# How can I make the ESM work with electron in my project?

Tags: javascript, electron

I've been trying fix for this a week now but can't really seem to find the problem.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53569631/2464270) but instead of having that project structure I've my own (see image below)

[image: Project structure]

In the *esm.js*:

```
require = require("esm")(module);
module.exports = require("./vickie.js");
```

Then i've changed *vickie.js*: 
 
From `const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')` 
 
To `import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron'`

Then I got this error

[image: Electron error]

In *package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "vickie",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./vickie.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ./vickie.js"
  },
  "author": "Arijanit",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "electron": "^8.2.3",
    "electron-builder": "^22.5.1",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "mysql2": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Why am I getting the error? Should I type in something extra in *package.json* to enable esm?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, have anyone find the correct answer?

Comment: Look like duplicate (even if this was first) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70478747/how-to-use-es-module-but-not-commonjs-with-electron-16/70658025#70658025

Comment: I got ESM support working with electron using electron-vite: https://evite.netlify.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a build tool that lets you use ESM in your own Electron code *and* modules installed from npm:

https://github.com/mifi/build-electron

To use it:

```
yarn add -D build-electron concurrently wait-on
```

Put your Electron main ESM source code in `src/main/index.js` and preload source in `src/preload/index.js`.

Add to your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "main": "build/main.js",
  "build": {
    "files": [
      "build/**/*"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently -k \"build-electron -d\" \"wait-on build/.build-electron-done && electron .\"",
    "build": "build-electron"
  }
```

Now create a configuration file in your project root `build-electron.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  mainEntry: 'src/main/index.js',
  preloadEntry: 'src/preload/index.js',
  outDir: 'build',
  mainTarget: 'electron16.0-main',
  preloadTarget: 'electron16.0-preload',
}
```

Now you can start developing:

```sh
npm run start
```

And to build your production app:

```sh
npm run build && npm exec electron-builder --mac
```